# Why the player never change walking speed never change animation/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main problem that it's never get inside any of the distance conditions the 10 or the 5. The player just keep walking nonstop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public float movingSpeed = 1f;
    public bool slowDown = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private bool startWaitingAnim = true;
    private bool endRot = false;
    private Vector3 originalPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        originalPos = anim.transform.position;
        anim.SetFloat("Walking Speed", movingSpeed);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(originalPos, new Vector3(anim.transform.position.x, anim.transform.position.y, anim.transform.position.z + 10));           

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10);

                anim.SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Idle", true);

            if (startWaitingAnim == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimation());
                startWaitingAnim = false;
            }

            anim.SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
            anim.SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
            if (!endRot)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(goalRotation, anim.transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                anim.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);

                // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
            }
        }
    }

    bool waitinganimation = false;
    IEnumerator WaitForAnimation()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        waitinganimation = true;
    }
}
```

I tried to put a break point on the condition :

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
```

But it's never stop there never get there inside and never do the code inside.
And never get inside the second condition if it's lower then 5 distance.

Screenshot of the inspector the script :

[image: Inspector]

And screenshot of the Animator :

[image: Animator]

Comment: maybe `slowDown` is never set?

Comment: It is in the inspector I tried to set it to true.

Comment: and did you check if `distanceFromTarget` actually gets small enough? If your Brakepoint is never called ... are you actually in Debug mode?

Comment: The problem I saw now is with my distanceFromTarget calculation. I wanted to make that when the player walked and his distance from a target is lower then 10 slow down and lower then 5 make the rest. But instead it's starting when the distance is already 10 and then distance get raising up. Then how can I set a target distance without using a gameobject ? I guess doing the new Vector3 part is wrong.

Comment: I wanted to set a distance target and if the distance from the target is lower then 10 do something and then lower from 5 do something else.

Comment: the problem is I can not see where your object is moving towards ... maybe it is simply not moving towards your target so the distance doesn't get smaller?

Comment: @derHugo In the animator I'm using a state WALK and in the state using the HumanoidWalk animation that is that make the player to move.

Comment: Found the solution : float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(anim.transform.position, new Vector3(originalPos.x, originalPos.y, originalPos.z + 20)); this is working. Now the player is walking then slow down then change animations smooth.